# How to obtain count of record differences in the same table, where there are distinct and nearly-distinct records

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, netezza

I've a table `TABLEA` with data as below

```
field1 field2 field3.......field16
123    10-JAN-12 0.8.......ABC
123    10-JAN-12 0.8.......ABC
.
.
.
123    10-JAN-12 0.7.......ABC
245    11-JAN-12 0.3.......CDE
245    11-JAN-12 0.3.......CDE
245    11-JAN-12 0.3.......XYZ
...
<unique rows>
```

When I do a

```
select field1, field2, ...field16 
  from TABLEA
```

I obtain M records,and when I do a

```
select distinct field1, field2...field16 
  from TABLEA
```

I obtain `M-x` records, where `M` is in the Millions and `x` is a much smaller #.

I am trying to write  SQL to get the x records (eventually, just get the count).
I've tried all Set operator keywords like

```
select field1...field16 
 from TABLEA 
 EXCEPT 
 select distinct field1..field16 
   from TABLEA
```

Or using `UNION ALL` instead of EXCEPT. But none of them return `x`, instead they all return 0 rows.

Answer (score 3):

You can select the rows that are not distinct by

```
 SELECT field1, ... , field16
   FROM tablea
  GROUP BY field1, ... , field16
 HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Edit: Another approach would be to use an analytical function `ROW_NUMBER()`, partitioning by all your `field` columns. The first (i.e. distinct) row for a given set of fields has `ROW_NUMBER = 1`, the second = 2, the third = 3 etc. So you can select the `x`-rows with `WHERE ROW_NUMBER > 1`.

```
CREATE TABLE tablea (
    field1 NUMBER, field2 DATE,  field3 NUMBER, field16 VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO tablea VALUES (123, DATE '2012-01-10', 0.8, 'ABC');
INSERT INTO tablea VALUES (123, DATE '2012-01-10', 0.8, 'ABC');
INSERT INTO tablea VALUES (123, DATE '2012-01-10', 0.7, 'ABC');
INSERT INTO tablea VALUES (245, DATE '2012-01-11', 0.3, 'CDE');
INSERT INTO tablea VALUES (245, DATE '2012-01-11', 0.3, 'CDE');
INSERT INTO tablea VALUES (245, DATE '2012-01-11', 0.3, 'XYZ');
```

To select the duplicate rows `x`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT field1, field2, field3, field16,
               ROWID AS rid,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
               field1, field2, field3, field16 ORDER BY ROWID) as rn
          FROM tablea
        )
  WHERE rn > 1;

 123 10.01.2012 0.8 ABC AAAJ6mAAEAAAAExAAB 2
 245 11.01.2012 0.3 CDE AAAJ6mAAEAAAAExAAE 2
```

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang. That query doesn't return the needed results. In fact, it just returns a single row. Unfortunately, the underlying table has been updated and my x has changed.

Answer (score 1):

you will get what you want with your own 'Except' query that you have posted above. But you must include the 'ALL' keyword in your except as 'Except Distinct' is the default. So I have just added the ALL keyword below in your query itself:

select field1...field16 
 from TABLEA 
 EXCEPT ***ALL***
 select distinct field1..field16 
   from TABLEA

If you want a count of the records of M-x then make the above query a subquery in the FROM clause of another query and have count in that outer query and you would get the count as shown below:

Select count(*) 
From 
(
select field1...field16 
 from TABLEA 
 EXCEPT ALL
 select distinct field1..field16 
   from TABLEA
) B

Guess this is what you are looking for.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to get a count of a row result that is not in your distinct, if your column choices are the same.  Distinct is showing a 'DISTINCT' possibility of all results so doing a union all is just going to repeat it and except is never going to find anything as you are limiting out your rows.  What are you trying to even do?  Try to count where the distincts are happening?  The answer you got from Wolfgang does that already.

```
declare @Table Table ( personID int identity, person varchar(8));

insert into @Table values ('Brett'),('Brett'),('Brett'),('John'),('John'),('Peter');


-- gives me all results
select person
from @Table

-- gives me distinct results (no repeats)
Select distinct person
from @Table


-- gives me nothing as nothing exists that is distinct that is not in total
select person
from @Table 
except 
select distinct person
from @Table

-- shows me counts of rows repeated by pivoting on one column and counting resultant rows from that.  Having clause adds predicate specific logic to hunt for.
-- in this case duplicates or rows greater than one
Select person, count(*)
from @Table 
group by person
having count(*) > 1
```

EDIT you can get a difference of the distinct from the total if that is what you mean:

```
 with dupes as 
    (
    Select count(*) as cnts, sum(count(*)) over() as TotalDupes
    from @Table 
    group by person 
    having count(*) > 1 -- dupes are defined by rows repeating 
    ) 
, uniques as 
    (
    Select count(*) as cnts, sum(count(*)) over() as TotalUniques
    from @Table 
    group by person 
    having count(*) = 1  -- non dupes are rows of only a single resulting row
    )
select distinct TotalDupes - TotalUniques as DifferenceFromRepeatsToUnqiues
from Dupes, Uniques
```

Comment: Thanks to you both for taking the time to help out.
What I'm trying to do is find the difference between the following two queries 
(1) select field1, field2,...field16 from TABLEA
and 
(2) select distinct field1, field2,...field16 from TABLEA 
When the counts are taken individually and subtracted there is a small difference (x). I am trying to find a query to provide  x records.

Comment: My 'Edit' may answer that question.  Although I am not certain what good this data would be.